# "Rounding" colour values to the nearest of a small set of colours

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, math, colors, rounding

**Preamble**

As a part of a project I'm working on I am trying to provide a convenient way to search for images in our system.  We currently provide searching by various types of user added metadata (e.g. title, description, keywords) and by various metadata which we extract (e.g. EXIF, IPTC, XMP, etc).  I would also like to add a "colour search" similar to what you can see in google's image search.

The project uses PHP and we can use the Imagemagick extension to segment and quantize the image and extract the most "significant" colours from the image; I'm not entirely certain of the results I'm getting here, but they seem reasonably accurate and certainly better than nothing.

**The Problem**

The bit that I'm having difficulty on is converting these significant colours into a set of representative colours, e.g. when you look at [Google's image search](http://www.google.com.au/images?hl=en&source=imghp&biw=1280&bih=687&q=food&gbv=2&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) there is a set of 12 colours there.  I'd like to mathematically "round" my colour value to the nearest representative colour, so that I can index the image with the colours that I detect and then facet my search results that way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking to round to those specific 12 colors in Google image search, or was that just an example of color rounding? If the latter, how many colors would you ideally like to end up with?

Comment: Those 12 would be fine, but I'm not fixed on them.  I think that an appropriate approach should work regardless of the values I'm rounding to, so I don't think the actual values are important.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The first step would be to define the colors you want to compare to.

The second step is to find the smallest distance from your color to one of the colors you chose in the previous step. In order to be able to measure that distance you need an Euclidian space in which to model colors.

Of course the simple choice would be the RGB space

[image]

And the distance between two colors C<sub>1</sub>(r<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>) and C<sub>2</sub>(r<sub>2</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>) would be

**sqrt( (r<sub>1</sub> - r<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (g<sub>1</sub> - g<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (b<sub>1</sub> - b<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> )**.

But if you need more precision it would be better to use the Hue-Chroma-Lightness bicone space, a derivative of the HSL cylinder.

[image]

In the RGB space things were straight forward as R, G and B where each on a separate axis. In HCL we need to compute the coordinates on each of the axis.

First of all we compute the chroma (which is a bit different from saturation) as:

**Chroma = max(Red, Green, Blue) - min(Red, Green, Blue)**

Then we normalize our H, C and L value so that H goes from 0 to 2 (to cover a circle if we multiply by PI and take radians as the unit), C goes from 0 to 1 (the radius of the trigonometric circle) and L goes from -1 (Black) to 1 (White).

Next we take **z = L** without any transformations as it is clear from the image that it goes along the vertical axis.

We can easily observe that for a color, Chroma is the distance from the z axis and Hue is the angle. So we get

**x = C * cos(H*PI)** and
**y = C * sin(H*PI)**

At this point x, y and z will all be in [-1, 1] and the distance between two colors will be, using the same formula as above,

**sqrt( (x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (z<sub>1</sub> - z<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> )**.

---

To get even more precision and find the closest color according to human color perception you could use the [CIE-L*ab](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH) modeling space and compute the distance with one of [these algorithms](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=DELT). The principles are the same as for the two cases presented above, only the algorithms are more complex.

---

**Update (7 years later)**

Finally xkcd featured a comic that I can use in this post!

[image]

https://xkcd.com/1882/

Comment: Alin, this definitely sounds interesting, but this is still a little too abstract for me; I have already implemented functions to convert RGB->HSL for other reasons (based on http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=18#text18), but I don't see an algorithm for converting to HCL there and I'm not clear from your post what I would do with it once the conversion was done.

Comment: @El Yobo I added some instructions on how to compute the distance in HCL. As for what to do with it once the conversion is done, the purpose is to be able to find as precise as possible "the closest color". For that you need to be able to compute "the distance" between colors. The RGB and HCL spaces I proposed give you a suitable medium in which to compute those distances.

Comment: @El Yobo Also I'm sorry if I explained if to abstractly. The main thing you need to understand is that you need a good way to spread the colors in space (a modeling space) so that similar colors are as close to each other as possible and that all colors are equally represented. And then check to see to which of your chosen colors a certain color is closest to.

Comment: I took a look on easyrgb.com and I saw that they offer all the tools you need to find the closest color. You first need to go from RGB to XYZ and then to CIE-L*ab representation. Then you can compute distances using one of the formulas here: http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=DELT I looks that these formulas are for human perceived color difference so I don't think there is anything better than that. Of course implementing may be a pain in the arse :)

Comment: Sounds really promising; I think I can implement those algorithms easily enough.  Hopefully I'll get time to have a go this week and will get back to you.

Comment: That's a nice descriptive answer. Respect for the effort!

Comment: Alin, I haven't had time check this out yet, but it looks very solid to me and the bounty is about to expire so I'm going to mark it correct.  I'll post an update once I get the time to implement it :)

Comment: Compute the square of the distance in colourspace, rather than the distance. Same "closest" color results, no square root calculation.

Comment: @Emilio Neglecting to extract the square root would make sense in most programming situations, but to be rigorous I think it is best to keep the formulas from the answer as they are now so that they verify the *triangle inequality*.

Comment: What does "precisely" mean here? This is not a nitpick; the definition of "precise" is essential to deciding which distance to use!

Comment: @Raphael Good point. The term "precisely" is not properly defined, but it is hinted that it should be interpreted as "closeness to human perception of colour". I could alter my answer to clarify this aspect, but if someone is really interested in this topic, I'm sure they will read the comments. Also, SO is a collaborative knowledge base. Feel free to edit, if you see improvement potential.

Answer (score 4):

```
function getSimilarColors (color) {
    var base_colors=["660000","990000","cc0000","cc3333","ea4c88","993399","663399","333399","0066cc","0099cc","66cccc","77cc33","669900","336600","666600","999900","cccc33","ffff00","ffcc33","ff9900","ff6600","cc6633","996633","663300","000000","999999","cccccc","ffffff"];

    //Convert to RGB, then R, G, B
    var color_rgb = hex2rgb(color);
    var color_r = color_rgb.split(',')[0];
    var color_g = color_rgb.split(',')[1];
    var color_b = color_rgb.split(',')[2];

    //Create an emtyp array for the difference betwwen the colors
    var differenceArray=[];

    //Function to find the smallest value in an array
    Array.min = function( array ){
           return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
    };


    //Convert the HEX color in the array to RGB colors, split them up to R-G-B, then find out the difference between the "color" and the colors in the array
    $.each(base_colors, function(index, value) { 
        var base_color_rgb = hex2rgb(value);
        var base_colors_r = base_color_rgb.split(',')[0];
        var base_colors_g = base_color_rgb.split(',')[1];
        var base_colors_b = base_color_rgb.split(',')[2];

        //Add the difference to the differenceArray
        differenceArray.push(Math.sqrt((color_r-base_colors_r)*(color_r-base_colors_r)+(color_g-base_colors_g)*(color_g-base_colors_g)+(color_b-base_colors_b)*(color_b-base_colors_b)));
    });

    //Get the lowest number from the differenceArray
    var lowest = Array.min(differenceArray);

    //Get the index for that lowest number
    var index = differenceArray.indexOf(lowest);

    //Function to convert HEX to RGB
    function hex2rgb( colour ) {
        var r,g,b;
        if ( colour.charAt(0) == '#' ) {
            colour = colour.substr(1);
        }

        r = colour.charAt(0) + colour.charAt(1);
        g = colour.charAt(2) + colour.charAt(3);
        b = colour.charAt(4) + colour.charAt(5);

        r = parseInt( r,16 );
        g = parseInt( g,16 );
        b = parseInt( b ,16);
        return r+','+g+','+b;
    }

    //Return the HEX code
    return base_colors[index];
}
```

Comment: What does this do? Why is it good? Code-only answers rarely helpful.

Comment: This javascript function rounds the input color(which is hex) to the nearest color set in the base_colors variable. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2tc3b1z6/1/

Comment: "Rounds" *how*? The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4356523/539599) shows that there are different approaches (in fact, there are infinitely many). Which is yours, and why is it better than others?

Comment: It seems you do geometric distance, which was given in answers before yours, and is not really a good solution.

Comment: The comments don't explain what you mean by "difference".

Comment: Exactly was I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a rough idea only - you will need to tweak it to your own needs.

Basically, I thought that, as colors are recorded as RGB, either as a Hex string "#000000" to "#ffffff", or as an RGB set "rgb(0,0,0)" to "rgb(255,255,255)", and these are interchangeable/translateable, this is a simple mathematical rounding issue.

In the full range of colors there would be (16*16)*(16*16)*(16*16) = 256*256*256 = 16,777,216 possible colors.

Rounding colors to their closest single character Hex value reduces that to 16*16*16 = 4,096 possible colors. Still far too many, but getting closer.

Rounding colors to a single character value, but then limiting that further to being one of 4 (0,3,7,f) reduces it to 4*4*4 = 32. Close enough for me.

So, I built a very basic PHP function to try and achieve this:

```
function coloround( $incolor ){
  $inR = hexdec( $incolor{0}.$incolor{1} )+1;
  $inG = hexdec( $incolor{2}.$incolor{3} )+1;
  $inB = hexdec( $incolor{4}.$incolor{5} )+1;
 # Round from 256 values to 16
  $outR = round( $outR/16 );
  $outG = round( $outG/16 );
  $outB = round( $outB/16 );
 # Round from 16 to 4
  $outR = round( $outR/4 );
  $outG = round( $outG/4 );
  $outB = round( $outB/4 );
 # Translate to Hex
  $outR = dechex( max( 0 , $outR*4-1 ) );
  $outG = dechex( max( 0 , $outG*4-1 ) );
  $outB = dechex( max( 0 , $outB*4-1 ) );
 # Output
  echo sprintf( '<span style="background-color:#%s;padding:0 10px;"></span> &gt; <span style="background-color:#%s;padding:0 10px;"></span>%s has been rounded to %s<br>' ,
         $incolor , $outR.$outG.$outB ,
         $incolor , $outR.$outG.$outB );
}
```

This function, when passed a hex string, echos a sample of the original color and a sample of the abbreviated color.

This is just a basic proof-of-concept, as I do not know the format Imagemagick is returning the colors as, but you may be able to utilise this logic to create your own.

From those 32 colors then, you could group the similar (there would probably be about 8 shades of grey in there) and name the remainder to allow your users to search by them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of colors you're looking for, why not try using bitwise operators (PHP's reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), since you mentioned it in the question) to reduce the number of significant digits? You could round the RGB values before shifting to increase accuracy as well.