# RGB to closest predefined color

Tags: php, function, colors, gd

**Edit:**

With the answer given I made this function

```
function grabclosestcolor($r, $g, $b){
    $colors = array(array(124,12,12),array(7,7,11),array(110,224,219),array(123,123,123),array(124,177,74),array(130,86,53),array(77,77,77),array(164,124,68),array(204,196,132),array(164,148,147),array(163,123,67),array(26,122,26), array(195,195,50),array(193,193,193),array(255,248,73),array(243,243,243));
    $differencearray = array();
    foreach ($colors as $value) {
        $difference = sqrt(pow($r-$value[0],2)+pow($g-$value[1],2)+pow($b-$value[2],2));
        array_push($differencearray, $difference);
        $smallest = min($differencearray);
        $key = array_search($smallest, $differencearray);
        return $colors[$key];
        }
    }
```

---

My goal is this. I grab a picture and loop through each pixel and grab its x,y, and rgb.

Instead of just grabbing the rgb, I have a predefined array and I'm looking for the closest match from the color I grabbed to the predefined array.
The goal here is to only use colors from the predefined array.
Here is my array of colors.

```
$colors = array(array(124,12,12),array(7,7,11),array(110,224,219),array(123,123,123),array(124,177,74),array(130,86,53),array(77,77,77),array(164,124,68),array(204,196,132),array(164,148,147),array(163,123,67),array(26,122,26), array(195,195,50),array(193,193,193),array(255,248,73),array(243,243,243));
```

and here is my existing code that loops through it all.

```
$int = imagesx($im) - 1;
$int2 = imagesy($im) - 1;
$start2 = 0;
do{
    $start = 0;
    do{
        $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $start, $start2);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
        $value = rgb2hex($r,$g,$b).":$start:$start2";
        array_push($colorsofimage, $value);
    } while($int > $start++);
} while($int2 > $start2++);
```

rgb2hex is a User Defined Function, but what I want to accomplish is to change that function with the function to grab the closest color.

$colorsofimage contains an array of each pixels info with hex:x:y
what i want it to be is rgb2hex(NEWFUNCTION($r,$g,$b));
So that the new hex is the 1 out of the predefined array.

I hope you understood, because I have no clue how to do it because I don't know the algorithm of a color.

Comment: Depending how hard out you want to go, the answer on my (similar) question may be of use - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057475/rounding-colour-values-to-the-nearest-of-a-small-set-of-colours

Comment: Again, I don't know PHP that well, but the function that you give as your solution looks considerably less efficient than the one I suggested earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485229/rgb-to-closest-predefined-color/4485327#4485327

Comment: why is there a return in the foreach loop?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to calculate the distance to each color, and pick the smallest.

There are a few ways to do this.  A simple method would be to calculate the distance would be:

```
sqrt((r-r1)^2+(g-g1)^2+(b-b1)^2)
```

A better method might be to incorporate the weighted values to calculate a distance, for instance the values used when converting RGB->YUV:

```
Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B
```

in that case you would use

```
sqrt(((r - r1) * .299)^2 + ((g - g1) * .587)^2 + ((b - b1) * .114)^2)
```

Of course, since you don't need the exact distances, just a comparison, you can and probably should just skip the square root, making the last calculation:

```
((r - r1) * .299)^2 + ((g - g1) * .587)^2 + ((b - b1) * .114)^2
```

Comment: Thanks for this, im going to edit the OP and put the function I made.

Comment: Random thought: Strictly speaking you don't need to take the square root and can just find the smallest square if performance is a concern.

Comment: @mootinator Why do we need to square the values at all? Why not just shortest distance?

Comment: @mootinator Are we squaring to eliminate negative values? Does anyone know if the absolute value function is faster than squaring? Or simply converting to a string and stripping the negative then converting back to a number, or maybe just multiplying itself by negative 1 if it's negative?

Comment: @Albert Renshaw We're squaring to find the euclidean distance between two points. We're skipping taking the square root of the distance because that step doesn't affect the sort order of the distances.

Comment: @mootinator Okay so it's the same as just taking the absolute value of the difference?

Comment: No. Simple example where they are definitely not the same: 5+5+5=15 Squared before adding=75. 1+1+12 = 14 Squared before adding = 144 Several people wouldn't have suggested squaring the differences if there were no point to it other than to remove negative values.

Comment: Obviously I meant to say 146 for that last calculation ;)

Comment: Euclidian distance gives me shoddy results: a gray of similar saturation may be closer than a similar hue with "more" different saturation. Since hue is the first humans notice, it should take precedence -- Euclidian distance does not do that, with or without weights.

Answer (score 11):

The [RGB colour-space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space) is simply a cube. In 24-bit colour each side has a length of 256, allowing values from 0 to 255. In order to find the closest colour in within this cube, you need a distance function. The simplest and most intuitive is the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance): if you have colour (r1, g1, b1) and another colour (r2, g2, b2) the distance would be `sqrt((r2-r1)^2 + (g2-g1)^2 + (b2-b1)^2)`.

The challenge for you is then to find the best match across all the values in your predefined array. I suggest that you start simply by iterating over all your values and check the distance for each in turn. Note that for this purpose you do not need to perform the `sqrt`, simply comparing on the sum of the squares would be sufficient, and would have the benefit of being all based in integer maths. My PHP isn't great, but roughly you would do:

```
function dist($col1,$col2) {
  $delta_r = $col1[0] - $col2[0];
  $delta_g = $col1[1] - $col2[1];
  $delta_b = $col1[2] - $col2[2];
  return $delta_r * $delta_r + $delta_g * $delta_g + $delta_b * $delta_b;
} 

$closest=$colors[0];
$mindist=dist($rgb,$colors[0]);
$ncolors=sizeof($colors);
for($i = 1; $i < $ncolors; ++$i)
{
    $currdist = dist($rgb,$colors[$i]);
    if($currdist<$mindist) {
      $mindist=$currdist;
      $closest=$colors[$i];
    }
}
```

There are more complicated distance functions (for instance, taking better account of psychovisual interpretation of colour differences (look into [Delta E](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#Delta_E)) but I suspect this is more than you need.

Comment: It's not necessarily a cube, even if it's commonly done so. It's primarily a vector space, and could as well be a paralleloid.

Comment: @user502515: It _could_ be, but it's unlikely. All the RGB colour spaces I've encountered (most obviously sRGB) tend to be bounded in the range 0 to 1 or 0 to 255. Other colour spaces, such as CIE Lab, do indeed have different bounds, but they are not RGB.

Comment: @beldaz why are we squaring the distance as well? Why not just take the sum of the distance of each color?

Comment: Is it to eliminate negative values? Are there quicker ways of doing this?

Comment: @Albert the sum of distances would be like walking around a square rather than walking directly across it: the distances are different (FWIW your approach is sometimes referred to as a Manhattan Distance).

Comment: @beldaz Okay that makes sense on a euclidean plane... but with colors there are 3 values... We take the square to remove any negative values but you are still just summing the "manhattan distance" of 2d values on a 3d region. Wouldn't you need to cube at that point?

Comment: @beldaz When you are comparing values to an array of fixed values if all distances are manhattan distances anyways wouldn't you still get the same result for "closest color" minus all the time you spend squaring those digits?

Comment: @beldaz If we are going to not use the `sqrt` function I mean... If we are going to use the `sqrt` function than it's the different between euclidean distances and manhattan distances... but if you are eliminating that than you are just taking my value and squaring it... The only reason we square is for absolute values... the sqrt gets us the true value but it can be eliminated since we are comparing distances to a static array... but if you are going to eliminate the sqrt you are taking the manhattan distance again, your numbers are just larger is all...

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw No, you don't need to cube your values. You always square them, regardless of the number of dimensions. This is from geometry. The point of squaring is not to get absolute numbers. The distance between two vectors using sum of the squares of the difference along each dimension will be different from Manhattan distance due to the cross terms generated by the squaring (not the sqrt of the result).

Comment: @beldaz Isn't the distance between the two vectors only the sum of the  distance after you square root it... if you are skipping the square root step you just have the manhattan distance with it's components squared. The point of squaring then square-rooting is to get the hypotenuse via the pythagorean theorem... but if you change the pythagorean theorem to not include a square root you are now just summing the squares of the legs (the manhattan distance with it's components squared)

Comment: @beldaz You CAN ignore the square-root because the closest value will be the same wether you square-root all values or don't square-root any values because the smallest number will product the smallest square-root value. But by that logic you don't have to square it either, you just need to make sure you have positive values otherwise you might end up subtracting distances, that's why you are leaving the square in but taking the square-root out... and if you are going to do that, why not take both out and just use absolute value? Smaller numbers 0:)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Yes, you can ignore the sqrt step, but I think you've misunderstood the squaring step. You square the distance in each dimension separately. The Euclidean distance is sqrt((r-r0)^2 + (g-g0)^2 + (b-b0)^2). This is different to the Manhattan distance (abs(r-r0) + abs(g-g0) + abs(b-b0)). Do the maths by expanding them out and you'll see that the former contains cross terms that the latter does not. It's not about positive or negative values.

Comment: @beldaz Well it is also about negative and positive values because a distance of -15 and a distance of 10 sum to -5 total distance when really it's 25 total distance... but that's besides the point.. what I'm saying is you are no longer finding euclidean distance if you ignore the square-root, you are now finding the sum of two separate distances (the manhattan rows/columns) squared. Euclidean distance works because of the Pythagorean theorem taking two lines (manhattan columns and rows) and averaging them into 1 hypotenuse... once you remove the sqrt you are no longer doing this.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Distances are typically magnitudes, with an associated direction vector. So you don't have a negative distance (Delta E) of -15, you'd have a distance of 15. A hypotenuse is not an average. Summing squares introduces cross terms that are there regardless of whether you sqrt the result or not, for anything more than one dimension.

Comment: @beldaz Sorry, "Average" was the wrong word :o) and when I take one red value and subtract the other red value sometimes I get negative values (negative distance) so I have to absolute value it (or square it) that's all I meant!:)

Comment: Doesn't this formula rather choose a different color instead of a different shade? I think I would go for a hsl translation first. ( not sure though ).

Comment: @Joeri The distinction between color and shade is rather subjective. In RGB there is no difference. HSL doesn't have shades either, but it does have hues and saturation. The problem is that there's no rudimentary distance function between two HSL coordinates. For a proper psychovisual color space with a well defined distance function you should use CIELab.

Comment: @beldaz thanks. I was just wondering if 255,255,255 was closer to 254,254,254 or 253,255,255.

Comment: Keeping things simple the first distance would be sqrt(3) and the second would be sqrt(4), so the last color would be further away. Whether it would look a more different color is another matter, and this is what psychovisual color spaces and their distance functions are for.

Comment: He thanks @beldaz. I've looked into CIElab but experts seem to agree that  some color differences are evaluated differently between the color difference ΔE*ab and the human eye... I'm going to look into this some more.

Answer (score 6):

Since this question is displayed in the top ten of goolge search results, here is a more complex function I wrote some years ago, which produced better results than the existing PHP functions.

```
/*
 * Die Funktion gibt den Array-Schlüssel der Farbe ($palette),
 * die am ehesten der Farbe $givenColor entspricht.
 * 
 * Returns the index of the palette-color which is most similar
 * to $givenColor.
 * 
 * $givenColor und die Einträge in $palette können entweder
 * Strings im Format (#)rrggbb
 * (z. B. "ff0000", "4da4f3" oder auch "#b5d7f3")
 * oder Arrays mit je einem Wert für Rot, Grün und Blau 
 * (z. B. $givenColor = array( 0xff, 0x00, 0x00 ) )
 * sein.
 * 
 * $givenColor and the colors in $palette should be either
 * formatted as (#)rrggbb
 * (e. g. "ff0000", "4da4f3" or "#b5d7f3")
 * or arrays with values for red, green and blue
 * (e. g. $givenColor = array( 0xff, 0x00, 0x00 ) )
 *
 * Referenzen/References:
 * function rgb2lab
 *   - http://www.f4.fhtw-berlin.de/~barthel/ImageJ/ColorInspector//HTMLHilfe/farbraumJava.htm
 *   - http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_RGB_to_XYZ.html
 *   - http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_XYZ_to_Lab.html
 *
 * function deltaE
 *   - http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_DeltaE_CMC.html
 */
function getNearestColor( $givenColor,
                          $palette = array('blue' => '0000ff','red' => 'ff0000','green' => '00ff00','yellow' => 'ffff00','black' => '000000','white' => 'ffffff','orange' => 'ff8800','purple' => 'ff00ff', 'teal' => '00ffff')
  )
{
  if(!function_exists('rgb2lab'))
  {
    function rgb2lab($rgb) {
      $eps = 216/24389; $k = 24389/27;
      // reference white D50
      $xr = 0.964221; $yr = 1.0; $zr = 0.825211;
      // reference white D65
      #$xr = 0.95047; $yr = 1.0; $zr = 1.08883;

      // RGB to XYZ
      $rgb[0] = $rgb[0]/255; //R 0..1
      $rgb[1] = $rgb[1]/255; //G 0..1
      $rgb[2] = $rgb[2]/255; //B 0..1

      // assuming sRGB (D65)
      $rgb[0] = ($rgb[0] <= 0.04045)?($rgb[0]/12.92):pow(($rgb[0]+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
      $rgb[1] = ($rgb[1] <= 0.04045)?($rgb[1]/12.92):pow(($rgb[1]+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
      $rgb[2] = ($rgb[2] <= 0.04045)?($rgb[2]/12.92):pow(($rgb[2]+0.055)/1.055,2.4);

      // sRGB D50
      $x =  0.4360747*$rgb[0] + 0.3850649*$rgb[1] + 0.1430804*$rgb[2];
      $y =  0.2225045*$rgb[0] + 0.7168786*$rgb[1] + 0.0606169*$rgb[2];
      $z =  0.0139322*$rgb[0] + 0.0971045*$rgb[1] + 0.7141733*$rgb[2];
      // sRGB D65
      /*$x =  0.412453*$rgb[0] + 0.357580*$rgb[1] + 0.180423*$rgb[2];
      $y =  0.212671*$rgb[0] + 0.715160*$rgb[1] + 0.072169*$rgb[2];
      $z =  0.019334*$rgb[0] + 0.119193*$rgb[1] + 0.950227*$rgb[2];*/

      // XYZ to Lab
      $xr = $x/$xr; $yr = $y/$yr; $zr = $z/$zr;

      $fx = ($xr > $eps)?pow($xr, 1/3):($fx = ($k * $xr + 16) / 116); $fy = ($yr > $eps)?pow($yr, 1/3):($fy = ($k * $yr + 16) / 116); $fz = ($zr > $eps)?pow($zr, 1/3):($fz = ($k * $zr + 16) / 116);

      $lab = array();
      $lab[] = round(( 116 * $fy ) - 16); $lab[] = round(500*($fx-$fy)); $lab[] = round(200*($fy-$fz));      
      return $lab;
    } // function rgb2lab
  }

  if(!function_exists('deltaE'))
  {
    function deltaE($lab1, $lab2)
    {
      // CMC 1:1
      $l = 1; $c = 1;

      $c1 = sqrt($lab1[1]*$lab1[1]+$lab1[2]*$lab1[2]); $c2 = sqrt($lab2[1]*$lab2[1]+$lab2[2]*$lab2[2]);

      $h1 = (((180000000/M_PI) * atan2($lab1[1],$lab1[2]) + 360000000) % 360000000)/1000000;

      $t = (164 <= $h1 AND $h1 <= 345)?(0.56 + abs(0.2 * cos($h1+168))):(0.36 + abs(0.4 * cos($h1+35)));
      $f = sqrt(pow($c1,4)/(pow($c1,4) + 1900));

      $sl = ($lab1[0] < 16)?(0.511):((0.040975*$lab1[0])/(1 + 0.01765*$lab1[0]));
      $sc = (0.0638 * $c1)/(1 + 0.0131 * $c1) + 0.638;
      $sh = $sc * ($f * $t + 1 -$f);

      return sqrt( pow(($lab1[0]-$lab2[0])/($l * $sl),2) + pow(($c1-$c2)/($c * $sc),2) + pow(sqrt(($lab1[1]-$lab2[1])*($lab1[1]-$lab2[1]) + ($lab1[2]-$lab2[2])*($lab1[2]-$lab2[2]) + ($c1-$c2)*($c1-$c2))/$sh,2) );
    } // function deltaE
  }

  if(!function_exists('colorDistance'))
  {
    function colorDistance($lab1,$lab2)
    {
      return sqrt(($lab1[0]-$lab2[0])*($lab1[0]-$lab2[0])+($lab1[1]-$lab2[1])*($lab1[1]-$lab2[1])+($lab1[2]-$lab2[2])*($lab1[2]-$lab2[2]));
    }
  }

  if(!function_exists('str2rgb'))
  {
    function str2rgb($str)
    {
      $str = preg_replace('~[^0-9a-f]~','',$str);
      $rgb = str_split($str,2);
      for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
        $rgb[$i] = intval($rgb[$i],16);

      return $rgb;
    } // function str2rgb
  }

  // split into RGB, if not already done
  $givenColorRGB = is_array($givenColor)?$givenColor:str2rgb($givenColor);
  $min = 0xffff;
  $return = NULL;

  foreach($palette as $key => $color)
  {
    // split into RGB
    $color = is_array($color)?$color:str2rgb($color);
    // deltaE
    #if($min >= ($deltaE = deltaE(rgb2lab($color),rgb2lab($givenColorRGB))))
    // euclidean distance
    if($min >= ($deltaE = colorDistance(rgb2lab($color),rgb2lab($givenColorRGB))))
    {
      $min = $deltaE;
      $return = $key;
    }
  }

  return $return;
}
```

Comment: for me this is the only proper answer!

Comment: Be aware that meanwhile there are [replacements for the Delta E algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) I used in the above code.
Nevertheless, if I were to implement a new color distance function today, I would use the DIN99c or DIN99d color spaces since they are easier and faster to calculate than CIE94 or CIEDE2000 while serving a similar quality.

Comment: Some explanation is in order. What does this do? Why is it better?

Comment: This function uses a color space in which the distances between the colors are similar to the human color perception.
This allows for a certain color to get the best matching color from a given palette.
But as I wrote: Today I would use an implementation of DIN99 to achieve this. The above function was written over 10 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the distance from the input color to all possible candidates of your palette, and then pick the one with the smallest distance as the one to replace it with.

Distance can be defined in any way you like; Euclidean distance seems workable for RGB cubes, cylinders or HSL/HSV cones.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in taking the square root. Finding the shortest distance is the same as finding the shortest squared distance. `sqrt` is an expensive operation, so just skip it.

Whether it really matters, of course, depends of how often your program will make this calculation, but it's still pointless to have it.