# Paint algorithm leaving white pixels at the edges when I color

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, paint

I am creating a drawing application. When I select a very dark color and paint inside the Panda's face, the edges are left white. I want my code to color entire area bound within the borders. This is the [LINK](http://colorpeutic.com/product.php?id=14). These are the functions that I am using in javascript. How can I make them better?

```
function matchOutlineColor(r, g, b, a) {

    return (r + g + b < 75 && a >= 50);
};

function matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB) {
    var r = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos],
        g = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1],
        b = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2],
        a = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos + 3];

    // If current pixel of the outline image is black
    if (matchOutlineColor(r, g, b, a)) {
        return false;
    }

    r = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos];
    g = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1];
    b = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2];

    // If the current pixel matches the clicked color
    if (r === startR && g === startG && b === startB) {
        return true;
    }

    // If current pixel matches the new color
    if (r === curColor.r && g === curColor.g && b === curColor.b) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};

function colorPixel(pixelPos, r, g, b, a) {
    colorLayerData.data[pixelPos] = r;
    colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1] = g;
    colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2] = b;
    colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 3] = a !== undefined ? a : 255;
};

function floodFill(startX, startY, startR, startG, startB) {

    document.getElementById('color-lib-1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('color-lib-2').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('color-lib-3').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('color-lib-4').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('color-lib-5').style.display = "none";

    change = false;

    var newPos,
        x,
        y,
        pixelPos,
        reachLeft,
        reachRight,
        drawingBoundLeft = drawingAreaX,
        drawingBoundTop = drawingAreaY,
        drawingBoundRight = drawingAreaX + drawingAreaWidth - 1,
        drawingBoundBottom = drawingAreaY + drawingAreaHeight - 1,
        pixelStack = [
            [startX, startY]
        ];

    while (pixelStack.length) {

        newPos = pixelStack.pop();
        x = newPos[0];
        y = newPos[1];

        // Get current pixel position
        pixelPos = (y * canvasWidth + x) * 4;

        // Go up as long as the color matches and are inside the canvas
        while (y >= drawingBoundTop && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
            y -= 1;
            pixelPos -= canvasWidth * 4;
        }

        pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
        y += 1;
        reachLeft = false;
        reachRight = false;

        // Go down as long as the color matches and in inside the canvas
        while (y <= drawingBoundBottom && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
            y += 1;

            colorPixel(pixelPos, curColor.r, curColor.g, curColor.b);

            if (x > drawingBoundLeft) {
                if (matchStartColor(pixelPos - 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
                    if (!reachLeft) {
                        // Add pixel to stack
                        pixelStack.push([x - 1, y]);
                        reachLeft = true;
                    }

                } else if (reachLeft) {
                    reachLeft = false;
                }
            }

            if (x < drawingBoundRight) {
                if (matchStartColor(pixelPos + 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
                    if (!reachRight) {
                        // Add pixel to stack
                        pixelStack.push([x + 1, y]);
                        reachRight = true;
                    }
                } else if (reachRight) {
                    reachRight = false;
                }
            }

            pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
        }
    }
};

// Start painting with paint bucket tool starting from pixel specified by startX and startY
function paintAt(startX, startY) {

    var pixelPos = (startY * canvasWidth + startX) * 4,
        r = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos],
        g = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1],
        b = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2],
        a = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 3];

    if (r === curColor.r && g === curColor.g && b === curColor.b) {
        // Return because trying to fill with the same color
        return;
    }

    if (matchOutlineColor(r, g, b, a)) {
        // Return because clicked outline
        return;
    }

    floodFill(startX, startY, r, g, b);

    redraw();
};
```

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle please? Actually it seems to be happening because of the pixellation, you need to blur out at the border regions i feel.

Comment: I don't know how to create a fiddle. The code code is available at http://colorpeutic.com/product.php?id=14 if you view the source.

Comment: It's hard doing so... can you try it out at https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You can download the file from here. http://www.filedropper.com/product

Comment: Please read about [mcve]s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using exact color fill for dithered/smoothed/antialiased/lossy_compressed image. That leaves pixels with even slightly different color uncolored (borders) creating artifacts. There are 2 easy ways how to remedy it:

1. **match close colors instead of exact**

   if you got 2 **RGB** colors `(r0,g0,b0)` and `(r1,g1,b1)` right now (if I see it right) your checking is like this:

   ```
   if ((r0!=r1)&&(g0!=g1)&&(b0!=b1)) colors_does_not_match;
   ```

   You should do instead this:

   ```
   if (((r0-r1)*(r0-r1))+((g0-g1)*(g0-g1))+((b0-b1)*(b0-b1))>treshold) colors_does_not_match;
   ```

   Where `treshold` is you max allowed distance^2 constant for filling. If too low treshold used the artifacts will remain. If too high treshold is used then the fill can bleed also to simila colors nearby ...

   If you want to have something more visually robust then you can [compare colors in **HSV** space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37476754/2521214).
2. **use enclosed border filling**

   It is basically the same as flood fill but you recolor all pixel not containing border color instead of only those containing start color. This will fill the area but there will be artifacts in the border (will be a bit tinner) but not as visually unpleasing as your current approach.
3. **I sometimes use color homogenity fill**

   This one is good for editing photographs where the colors are shaded due to lighting or whatever. So I fill colors like in flood fill but the color match is considered if the color is not too far from start position by big treshold and not to far from last filled position with small treshold at the same time. This way I usually repair sky artifacts in stitched photos  by recoloring to common color and blur the area out with some spray tool gradient patterns...

**[Edit1] C++ examples**

It uses **VCL** encapsulated **GDI** bitmap so rewrite the image access to your style. Also you can ignore the window stuff (I left it only to show how to use this...). I implemented both methods **#1,#2** so choose which you want. Your borders are not sharp so the treshold is quite big (`223^2`) making the **#2** option unstable. The `static` variables are only to ease up heap stack trashing so if you want to multithread this you need to remove it ...

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// variables
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=NULL;            // your image
union color { DWORD dd; BYTE db[4]; };  // direct RGB channel access
DWORD **pixel=NULL;                     // direct 32bit pixel access
int xs=0,ys=0;                          // image resolution
int mx=0,my=0;                          // mouse position
int treshold=50000;                     // color match treshold
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Flood fill
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD _floodfill_col_fill;              // temp storage to ease up recursion heap/stack trashing
DWORD _floodfill_col_start;             // temp storage to ease up recursion heap/stack trashing
void _floodfill(int x,int y)            // recursive subfunction do not call this directly
    {
    // variables
    static color c;
    static int r,g,b;
    // color match
    c.dd=pixel[y][x]&0x00FFFFFF;        // mask out alpha channel just to be sure
    if (_floodfill_col_fill==c.dd) return;  // ignore already filled parts (exact match)
    r=c.db[0];  // r0,g0,b0
    g=c.db[1];
    b=c.db[2];
    c.dd=_floodfill_col_start;
    r-=c.db[0]; r*=r; // (r0-r1)^2,(g0-g1)^2,(b0-b1)^2
    g-=c.db[1]; g*=g;
    b-=c.db[2]; b*=b;
    if (r+g+b>treshold) return;
    // recolor
    pixel[y][x]=_floodfill_col_fill;
    // 4 neighboars recursion
    if (x>   0) _floodfill(x-1,y);
    if (x<xs-1) _floodfill(x+1,y);
    if (y>   0) _floodfill(x,y-1);
    if (y<ys-1) _floodfill(x,y+1);
    }
void floodfill(int x,int y,DWORD col)   // This is the main call for flood fill (x,y) start position and col is fill color
    {
    // init variables
    _floodfill_col_start=pixel[y][x]&0x00FFFFFF;
    _floodfill_col_fill =col        &0x00FFFFFF;
    // sanity check
    color c;
    int r,g,b;
    c.dd=_floodfill_col_fill;
    r=c.db[0];
    g=c.db[1];
    b=c.db[2];
    c.dd=_floodfill_col_start;
    r-=c.db[0]; r*=r;
    g-=c.db[1]; g*=g;
    b-=c.db[2]; b*=b;
    if (r+g+b<=treshold) return;
    // fill
    _floodfill(x,y);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Border fill
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD _borderfill_col_fill;             // temp storage to ease up recursion heap/stack trashing
DWORD _borderfill_col_border;           // temp storage to ease up recursion heap/stack trashing
void _borderfill(int x,int y)           // recursive subfunction do not call this directly
    {
    // variables
    static color c;
    static int r,g,b;
    // color match
    c.dd=pixel[y][x]&0x00FFFFFF;            // mask out alpha channel just to be sure
    if (_borderfill_col_fill==c.dd) return; // ignore already filled parts (exact match)
    r=c.db[0];  // r0,g0,b0
    g=c.db[1];
    b=c.db[2];
    c.dd=_borderfill_col_border;
    r-=c.db[0]; r*=r; // (r0-r1)^2,(g0-g1)^2,(b0-b1)^2
    g-=c.db[1]; g*=g;
    b-=c.db[2]; b*=b;
    if (r+g+b<=treshold) return;
    // recolor
    pixel[y][x]=_borderfill_col_fill;
    // 4 neighboars recursion
    if (x>   0) _borderfill(x-1,y);
    if (x<xs-1) _borderfill(x+1,y);
    if (y>   0) _borderfill(x,y-1);
    if (y<ys-1) _borderfill(x,y+1);
    }
void borderfill(int x,int y,DWORD col_fill,DWORD col_border)    // This is the main call for border fill (x,y) start position then fill and border colors
    {
    // init variables
    _borderfill_col_fill  =col_fill  &0x00FFFFFF;
    _borderfill_col_border=col_border&0x00FFFFFF;
    // sanity check
    color c;
    int r,g,b;
    c.dd=_borderfill_col_fill;
    r=c.db[0];
    g=c.db[1];
    b=c.db[2];
    c.dd=_borderfill_col_border;
    r-=c.db[0]; r*=r;
    g-=c.db[1]; g*=g;
    b-=c.db[2]; b*=b;
    if (r+g+b<=treshold) return;
    // fill
    _borderfill(x,y);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Window code
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    // [init event]

    // input image
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;          // VCL encapsulated GDI bitmap rewrite/use to whatever you got instead
    bmp->LoadFromFile("test.bmp");      // cropped part of your image
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;              // allow direct pixel access
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;           // set 32bit pixels for easy addressing
    xs=bmp->Width;                      // get the image size
    ys=bmp->Height;
    ClientWidth=xs;                     // just resize my App window to match image size
    ClientHeight=ys;
    // direct pixel access
    pixel = new DWORD*[ys];             // buffer for pointers to all lines of image
    for (int y=0;y<ys;y++)              // store the pointers to avoid slow GDI/WinAPI calls latter
     pixel[y]=(DWORD*)bmp->ScanLine[y];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // [exit event]
    delete bmp;
    delete pixel;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // [on paint event]
    Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormClick(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // [on mouse click event]
    floodfill(mx,my,0x00FF0000);
//  borderfill(mx,my,0x00FF0000,0x00000000);
    Paint();    // shedule repaint event
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int X,int Y)
    {
    // [on mouse move event]
    mx=X; my=Y; // store actual mouse position
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And gfx result:

[image: example]

**[Edit2] iterative segmented flood fill**

The problem with standard recursive flood fill is that it is potentially dangerous and often leads to Stack Overflows for larger or complicated fills (for example try a spiral with many screws ...) not to mention it is usually slow. The amount of memory needed for flood fill is a around multiple of filled pixels count (so take all of the variables and operands you use and multiply by image size in pixels and soon you hit huge numbers).

To avoid that you can limit the recursion layers a lot by using line segments instead of pixels. That will speed up everything and limit memory usage a lot. Also this approach can be done iteratively which is better in this case so the algorithm is like this:

1. **have a list of line segments `seg[]`**

   I chose horizontal lines so each segment has `x0,x1,y` and some flag variable `done` for later use. From start the list is empty.
2. **add new segment from filling start position `x,y`**

   So just scan all the pixels before and after `x,y` horizontally to cover all consequent start colors (`col0`) to the left `x0` and right `x1` and add new segment to the list with flag `done=0`.
3. **loop all segments with `done=0`**

   Set its `done=1` and scan all pixels neighboring it `x=<x0,x1>` and `y={y-1,y+1}` if found try to add new segment (just as in **#2**) but before adding it test all other segments for overlaps. If any overlapping segments are found enlarge it with newly found segment and set its `done=0` otherwise add the new segment. This way the segment count will not be too high.
4. **loop #3 while any changes has been made**

   To speed up this you can use index tables `idx[][]` that will hold all the indexes of segments at specific `y` coordinate. I set/use it so `segment[idx[y][?]].y=y`
5. **loop all the segments and recolor pixels**

Here the **C++** code of my for this:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// variables
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=NULL;            // your image
union color { DWORD dd; BYTE db[4]; };  // direct RGB channel access
DWORD **pixel=NULL;                     // direct 32bit pixel access
int xs=0,ys=0;                          // image resolution
int mx=0,my=0;                          // mouse position
int treshold=50000;                     // color match treshold
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Color compare with treshold
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool color_equal(DWORD c0,DWORD c1)
    {
    static color c;
    static int r,g,b;
    c.dd=c0&0x00FFFFFF;     // mask out alpha channel just to be sure
    r=c.db[0];              // r0,g0,b0
    g=c.db[1];
    b=c.db[2];
    c.dd=c1&0x00FFFFFF;
    r-=c.db[0]; r*=r;       // (r0-r1)^2,(g0-g1)^2,(b0-b1)^2
    g-=c.db[1]; g*=g;
    b-=c.db[2]; b*=b;
    return (r+g+b<=treshold);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool color_nonequal(DWORD c0,DWORD c1)
    {
    static color c;
    static int r,g,b;
    c.dd=c0&0x00FFFFFF;     // mask out alpha channel just to be sure
    r=c.db[0];              // r0,g0,b0
    g=c.db[1];
    b=c.db[2];
    c.dd=c1&0x00FFFFFF;
    r-=c.db[0]; r*=r;       // (r0-r1)^2,(g0-g1)^2,(b0-b1)^2
    g-=c.db[1]; g*=g;
    b-=c.db[2]; b*=b;
    return (r+g+b>treshold);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Flood fill segmented by lines
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct _segment
    {
    int x0,x1,y;
    int done;
    _segment(){}; _segment(_segment& a){ *this=a; }; ~_segment(){}; _segment* operator = (const _segment *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*_segment* operator = (const _segment &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
    };
void floodfill_segmented(int x,int y,DWORD col) // This is the main call for flood fill (x,y) start position and col is fill color
    {
    // init variables
    int i,j,k,e,ee,x0,x1;
    _segment s,*p;
    List<_segment> seg;     // H-line segments
    List< List<int> > idx;  // index table seg[idx[y]].y=y to speed up searches
    DWORD col0=pixel[y][x]&0x00FFFFFF;
    DWORD col1=col        &0x00FFFFFF;
    // sanity check
    if (color_equal(col0,col1)) return;
    // prepare segment table and macros
    seg.allocate(ys<<3); seg.num=0;
    idx.allocate(ys   ); idx.num=ys; for (i=0;i<ys;i++) idx.dat[i].num=0;
    // add new segment at (x,y)
    // scan the line to enlarge it as much as can
    // merge with already added segment instead of adding new one if they overlap
    // ee=1 if change has been made
    #define _seg_add                                                                 \
        {                                                                            \
        s.x0=x; s.x1=x; s.y=y; s.done=0;                                             \
        for (x=s.x0;x>=0;x--) if (color_equal(col0,pixel[y][x])) s.x0=x; else break; \
        for (x=s.x1;x<xs;x++) if (color_equal(col0,pixel[y][x])) s.x1=x; else break; \
        for (ee=0,k=0;k<idx.dat[s.y].num;k++)                                        \
            {                                                                        \
            j=idx.dat[s.y].dat[k]; p=seg.dat+j;                                      \
            if ((p->x0>=s.x0)&&(p->x0<=s.x1)) ee=1;                                  \
            if ((p->x1>=s.x0)&&(p->x1<=s.x1)) ee=1;                                  \
            if ((p->x0<=s.x0)&&(p->x1>=s.x0)) ee=1;                                  \
            if ((p->x0<=s.x1)&&(p->x1>=s.x1)) ee=1;                                  \
            if (ee)                                                                  \
                {                                                                    \
                if (p->x0>s.x0) { p->done=0; p->x0=s.x0; }                           \
                if (p->x1<s.x1) { p->done=0; p->x1=s.x1; }                           \
                s=*p;                                                                \
                break;                                                               \
                }                                                                    \
            }                                                                        \
        if (ee) ee=p->done; else { idx.dat[s.y].add(seg.num); seg.add(s); }          \
        }
    // first segment;
    _seg_add;
    for (e=1;e;)
        {
        // add new adjacent segments
        for (e=0,p=seg.dat,i=0;i<seg.num;i++,p++)
         if (!p->done)
            {
            p->done=1;
            y=p->y-1; if (y>=0) for (x=p->x0;x<=p->x1;x++) if (color_equal(col0,pixel[y][x])) { _seg_add; e|=!ee; x=s.x1; p=seg.dat+i; }
            y=p->y+1; if (y<ys) for (x=p->x0;x<=p->x1;x++) if (color_equal(col0,pixel[y][x])) { _seg_add; e|=!ee; x=s.x1; p=seg.dat+i; }
            }
        }
    #undef seg_add
    // recolor
    for (p=seg.dat,i=0;i<seg.num;i++,p++)
     for (x=p->x0,y=p->y;x<=p->x1;x++)
      pixel[y][x]=col;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `color_equal` just compares colors with tresholds (and also it should be a macro instead of a function to gain more speed).

I also use mine dynamic list template so:

- `List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`
- `xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list
- `xxx[7]` access array element (safe)
- `xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)
- `xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array
- `xxx.reset()` clears the array and set xxx.num=0
- `xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

Here something to compare to:

[image: example]

On the left is source image `720x720` pixels spiral and on the right is the result after filling from the bottom left side It took `40 ms` Code without using `idx[]` and using array range checks took around `440 ms` instead. If I use standard flood fill it crashes with stack overflow after few seconds. On the other hand for smaller fills the standard recursive flood fill is usually faster then this.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. Can you tell me where and how should I change my code?

Comment: @AliZia for example `function matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)` rewrite `if (r === startR && g === startG && b === startB)` style condition to the euclidean distance in bullet **#1**

Comment: In this function I have just 1 set of r,g,b. Where is the second one?

Comment: @AliZia one s the start color and second is the current position to fill pixel color

Comment: It is so confusing. :(

Comment: when you click then the start color is the color of the pixel mouse points to `(r0,g0,b0)`. During flood fill you pick 4 neighboring pixels each one is the `(r1,g1,b1)`  and check if fill it or not. so there you got  the 2 colors

Comment: I am starting to get a little bit now. Can you please rewrite the function for me?

Comment: @AliZia I do not code in javascript so no. I could write a simple floodfill in C++ for you instead if it helps. anyway your flood fill has a lot of code it should be much smaller in my opinion.

Comment: you can write it in c++. I will change it accordingly. what should be the threshold value?

Comment: @AliZia any value that leads to good results... I would have a scroll bar to adjust it on the run... if your RGB channels are `<0,255>` then max distance is `3*(255^2)` so any number between zero and it ... zero means only the exact color is matched and the max all colors are matched ...

Comment: @AliZia I am going tocode the flood fill it will take me few minutes ...

Comment: okay do it. thanks..

Comment: @AliZia done added edit1

Comment: @AliZia there is also another option and that is binarise the grayscale image first and the use that ... then do not use lossy image compressions or anti-aliasing or smooth filters ...

Comment: @AliZia added [edit2]