# How to Fill color inside shape using setPixel method?

Tags: java, image-processing, pixel

I need to fill the color inside custom shape. I know one of the pixel coordinate inside the shape and also know the color of the shape. I need to get all pixel inside the shape calculate from knowing pixel coordinate how can i write logic for this can some one please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **For already rendered shapes**

   use **Flood Fill** or **Boundary fill** algorithms. For example see:

   - [my C++ implementation of Flood&Boundary fill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37810355/2521214)

   beware most implementations are recursive so there is a high risk of stack/heap overflow for bigger areas. There are also iterative approaches using dynamic point lists which are safer.
2. **For polygons in vector form**

   Use **convex polygon** filling. In case you got **concave polygons** you need to divide them into **convex polygons** first. Another options is to triangulate. Both triangle and convex polygon rasterization is the same see:

   - [Algorithm to fill triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39062479/2521214)
   - [how to rasterize rotated rectangle (in 2d by setpixel)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19078088/2521214)

   If you need triangulation see:

   - [Wiki: Polygon triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation)

   In case of very complicated shapes and not possible triangulation for any reason you can try fill all the pixels in the bounding box of polygon that are inside polygon. For that you need:

   - [hit-test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24465094/2521214)