# Boundary fill algorithm in opengl c++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, bgi, cg

How can i implement the boundary fill algorithm using opengl and c++ i search online and  found this code

```
  #include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <dos.h> void bfill(int x,int y,int fill,int border)
{
    if((getpixel(x,y)!=border)&&(getpixel(x,y)!=fill))
    {
        delay(8);
        putpixel(x,y,fill);

        bfill(x+1, y,fill,border);
            bfill(x, y+1,fill,border);
            bfill(x-1, y,fill,border);
            bfill(x, y-1,fill,border);          
    }
}
void main()
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\Tc\\BGI");
    rectangle(10,50,50,10);
    bfill(11,12,MAGENTA,WHITE);
    getch();
```

but it's using BGI can anyone help?

This is my code:

```
#include <windows.h> // Header file for Windows
#include <gl/gl.h> // Header file for the OpenGL Library
#include <gl/glu.h> // Header file for the GLu32 Library
#include <gl/glut.h>

#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>



using namespace std;

void draw_XOY(){
glBegin(GL_LINES);
//xox'
glVertex2d(-1000, 0);
glVertex2d(1000, 0);
//yoy'
glVertex2d(0, -1000);
glVertex2d(0, 1000);
glEnd();
}


void dda_line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
cout<<"Draw Line from "<<"("<<x1<<" , "<<y1<<")"<< " To "<<"("<<x2<<" , "<<y2<<")"<<endl;
float x,y,dx,dy,step;
int i;

glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

dx=x2-x1;
dy=y2-y1;

if(dx>=dy)
step=dx;
else
step=dy;

dx=dx/step;
dy=dy/step;

x=x1;
y=y1;

i=1;
while(i<=step)
{
glVertex2d(x,y);
x=x+dx;
y=y+dy;
i=i+1;
}

glEnd();

cout<<endl<<endl;
}


void draw_up_ellipse(int a, int b, int k, int h){
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

float pi = 3.14121324;

glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for(float i = 0; i <= pi; i+=0.01){
x = a * cos(i) ;
y = b * sin(i) ;
cout<<x<<", "<<y<<endl;
glVertex2d(x+k, y+h);
}
glEnd();
}


void draw_down_ellipse(int a, int b, int k, int h){
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

float pi = 3.14121324;

glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for(float i = pi; i <= 2*pi; i+=0.01){
x = a * cos(i) ;
y = b * sin(i) ;
cout<<x<<", "<<y<<endl;
glVertex2d(x+k, y+h);
}
glEnd();
}


// draw function
static void redraw(void);

//main function
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc,argv); // init the window with args
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH); //determine display MODE
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0); //the position of window
glutInitWindowSize(1200,1200); // size w X h
glutCreateWindow("First Example"); // create the window with this title
glutDisplayFunc(redraw); // draw function (contains al drawing stmts.)

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // eye = camera look position and 'theta'
gluPerspective(45,1.0,0.1,1000.0); // theta, w/h , near, far
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //return to model view matrix

glutMainLoop(); // re-run
return 0; //return 0
}

// implementation of draw function
static void redraw(void)
{
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // determine clear color
glClearDepth(1.0); // depth clearaty
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // real clear
glLoadIdentity(); // load all init of I (eye to (0,0,0) )

glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // color of drawing geometries
glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-200.0f); // all to back (( to see result))
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // ???

//pixel size
glPointSize(3);
glLineWidth(2);

draw_XOY();

glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

dda_line(20, 10, 30, 20);
dda_line(30, 20, 40, 10);
dda_line(35, 0, 40, 10);
dda_line(25, 0, 35, 0);
dda_line(25, 0, 20, 10);
dda_line(20, 10, 35, 0);
dda_line(20, 10, 40, 10);
dda_line(35, 0, 30, 20);
dda_line(25, 0, 30, 20);
dda_line(25, 0, 40, 10);



glTranslated(-30,40,0);

glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
dda_line(-40, 0, -30, 0);
dda_line(-30, 0, -20, 0);
dda_line(-20, 0, -10, 0);
dda_line(-10, 0, 0, 0);

glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

draw_up_ellipse(10,8,-10,0);
draw_up_ellipse(15,13,-15,0);
draw_down_ellipse(15,8,-5,0);
draw_down_ellipse(20,13,0,0);

draw_up_ellipse(20,18,-10,0);
draw_up_ellipse(15,13,-15,0);
draw_down_ellipse(30,23,0,0);

draw_up_ellipse(30,23,-10,0);
draw_up_ellipse(35,28,-5,0);

glutSwapBuffers(); // to show frame in back buffer( no noise)
}
```

And I need to fill this (shape on the left):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please explain what happens when you try this code, and why you need to do it. It's actually better, when using OpenGL and other graphics acceleration languages, to obtain the shape you need to fill as a polygon, then use the libTess library to convert it into triangles, then draw the triangles using the standard OpenGL method for doing so.

Comment: I have to use opengl i want to fill this shape (on the left )  in the[link here ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qtj7qFxRXFS0wXN_CrKJln8wHnKIxrGu/view)  there is a screenshot and in this link is my  [fullcode ](https://justpaste.it/4jqpi)

Comment: oh god, BGI code.. wh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got 2 options:

1. **Implement boundary fill**

   but that is not how **OpenGL** works so it would be SLOOOOOW (using `glReadPixels` for reading individual pixels) unless you copy your screen into CPU side memory (with single `glReadPixels` call) fill on **CPU** side (SW rendering) there and then copy back to screen (single textured QUAD covering screen). For more info see:

   - [my C++ implementation of Flood&Boundary fill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37810355/2521214)

   just ignore the **VCL** stuff (the filling does not use it anyway) and convert the pixel array `DWORD **pixel=NULL;` to your pixel format.  Btw using linear 1D array behind will ease up the texture stuff later on. This is how to read entire screen and write it back:

   - [OpenGL Scale Single Pixel Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654398/2521214)

   to read individual pixels you can do:

   ```
   BYTE color[3];
   glReadPixels(x,y,1,1,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,color);
   ```

   in case you do not know what `BYTE/DWORD` is (and call your self a programmer) `BYTE` is 8 bit unsigned int and `DWORD` is 32 bit unsigned int ... some compilers and languages does not have it anymore so if the case use what you have or create it by `typedef` ...

   You can even port your **BGI** code (due to your lack of formatting I overlooked the `bfill` implementation at first look) just write `putpixel` and `getpixel` functions with GL counterparts. AND REMOVE THE `delay` !!! for example:
2. **convert your shape into convex polygons and render as such**

   OpenGL can render such shapes with filling natively and fast. Just render as `glBegin(GL_POLYGON)/glEnd()` or [triangulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) and use `GL_TRIANGLE` instead (like ear clipping).

   So instead of rendering your elliptic arces pixel by pixel store them into list of points in **CPU** side memory. Triangulate or reorder into convex polygons and then render with `for` loop inside `glBegin/glEnd` (or use **VBO** and `glDraw`)...

   So you would also need to add direction of the arces into your function and some target list of points.