# SvgColourServer from Svg.Skia library renders SVG with invalid color format

Tags: c#, svg

I have searched high and low for this and can't find anything.

I open an SVG file, iterate the elements and change a color, simply as so:

`child.Fill = new SvgColourServer(Color.Red);`

When I save the SVG to file, it saves it in some odd format I have never seen before:

`<rect ... style="fill:255, 0, 0;" />`

It should look like this:

`<rect ... style="fill:#ff0000" />`

I thought maybe this is some new format I wasn't aware of, but no, Chrome also complains:

[image: chrome]

How do you get `Svg.Skia` (0.5.18) to render colors correctly instead of whatever it's doing now?

Comment: https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/Svg.Skia/issues/100

Comment: @RobertLongson -- holy crap it's a bug that started in 0.5.11 and exists today even in preview versions. I really appreciate your help on your research. If you want to add an answer, i'll accept it. [This](https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/Svg.Skia/issues/100#issuecomment-1221625318) is the post that has the proof. I rolled back to 0.5.10 and it works fine now.

Comment: Not sure a link to a github issue counts as an answer. Doesn't look too difficult to fix though.

Comment: In the meantime, you should report this issue to the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround to this problem was to make sure the color is always passed to `Svg.Skia` as a known (named) color, because `Svg.Skia` then seems to generate a valid SVG element.

`ColorTranslator` [is calling](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/ColorTranslator.cs,228) `Color.FromArgb(int, int, int)` which will return an unnamed `Color`, like `"128, 64, 32"`. As pointed out in the comments already, due to a change in `Svg.Skia` version 0.5.11, this RGB value will be used and a corrupt SVG element is created:

```
<path ... style="fill:0, 128, 64, 32;" />
```

However, if color is a known (named) `Color`, then `Svg.Skia` will insert a SVG element which seems to be valid:

```
<path ... style="fill:Red;" />
```

To support all possible colors, I calculate the closest known color, by using the code [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323363/909180).

```cs
public static Color FromHtml(string htmlColor)
{
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(htmlColor);
 
    var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(htmlColor);
    var closestDistance = double.MaxValue;
    
    var closest = Color.White;
    var knownColors = Enum.GetValues<KnownColor>().Select(Color.FromKnownColor);
    
    foreach (var knownColor in knownColors)
    {
        // Calculate Euclidean distance
        var rDistSqrd = Math.Pow(color.R - knownColor.R, 2);
        var gDistSqrd = Math.Pow(color.G - knownColor.G, 2);
        var bDistSqrd = Math.Pow(color.B - knownColor.B, 2);
        var distance = Math.Sqrt(rDistSqrd + gDistSqrd + bDistSqrd);

        if (!(distance < closestDistance))
        {
            continue;
        }

        closestDistance = distance;
        closest = knownColor;
    }

    if (!closest.IsNamedColor)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("HTML color cannot be converted to a named color.", nameof(htmlColor));
    }

    return closest;
}
```

And tests:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("#FFEBCD", KnownColor.BlanchedAlmond)]
[DataRow("#ffebcd", KnownColor.BlanchedAlmond)]
[DataRow("#ff6e6e", KnownColor.Salmon)]
[DataRow("#8ccbff", KnownColor.LightSkyBlue)]
[DataRow("#210ca5", KnownColor.DarkBlue)]
public void CanCallFromHtml(string htmlColor, KnownColor expected)
{
    // Act
    var knownColor = KnownColorHelper.FromHtml(htmlColor);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(Color.FromKnownColor(expected), knownColor);
}
```