# Hexadecimal rounding in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, colors

Is it possible to round hex colors to previously set hex colors? Like I would put colors in an array and round other colors to the closest color in that array.

If it's possible, how would I implement that?

Comment: What does "previously set hex colors" mean?

Comment: I would specify a list of colors in an array

Comment: Convert the hexadecimal string to a number (if it isn't already), [round it to the nearest value in your array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-the-closest-number-out-of-an-array), then convert it back to a hexadecimal string.

Comment: @Ivar Will hex colors work?

Comment: @pineapplerind0215 Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8575671/479156).